# FindStr with regex

Tags: regex, batch-file, dos

I have a system log file like following:

```
</t>Processed 8 rows.<LF>
</t>Success:    8<LF>
</t>Skip:       0<LF>
</t>Error:      0<LF>
</t>Exceptions: 0<LF>

// other log details

</t>Processed 8 rows.<LF>
</t>Success:    6<LF>
</t>Skip:       1<LF>
</t>Error:      1<LF>
</t>Exceptions: 0<LF>
```

`<\t>` is tab character, `<LF>` is line feed character.

My job need to create a dos batch to examine these files, and take action if any `Skip`, `Error` or `Exceptions` found.

What's on my mind is using `findstr` with `regular expression` to locate any line have case fail, I have tested this regex:

```
// Should be one line here
\t+Skip\:\s+([1-9]|[1-9][0-9])\n|
\s+Error\:\s+([1-9]|[1-9][0-9])\n|
\s+Exceptions\:\s+([1-9]|[1-9][0-9])\n
```

However, findstr do not accept normal regular expression (\t\s\n...), so I did split into 6 regex:

```
findstr /rc:"Skip\:[ ]*[1-9]" %file%
findstr /rc:"Skip\:[ ]*[1-9][0-9]" %file%
findstr /rc:"Error\:[ ]*[1-9]" %file%
findstr /rc:"Error\:[ ]*[1-9][0-9]" %file%
findstr /rc:"Exceptions\:[ ]*[1-9]" %file%
findstr /rc:"Exceptions\:[ ]*[1-9][0-9]" %file%
```

Which this job required to use dos batch only (it's sad but can't change), do any way to simply the findstr syntax? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one `findstr` with all the matching cases

```
findstr /r /c:"Skip: *[1-9]" /c:"Error: *[1-9]" /c:"Exceptions: *[1-9]"  input.txt
```

Two `findstr` commands piped. First one extracts the required lines and second one search for problem conditions

```
findstr /l "Skip: Error: Exceptions:" input.txt | findstr /r /c:": *[1-9].*"
```

First option is faster as it involves only one command. Second option is less redundant and less prone to typing errors.

Comment: Really thanks, I don't know I can pass multiple `/c` in findstr